# Unable to perform enter key on anchor element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Java version: 7, Selenium version: 2.45

I am unable to perform ENTER on a link (anchor tag) using the sendKeys method.

Step1: Perform `TAB` using the `sendKeys` method (this works). Said link has focus. I can manually press `ENTER` on my keyboard and it will trigger the link.

Step2: Perform `ENTER` (or `RETURN`) using the `sendKeys` method (does not work).

I have tried:

- Adding `thread.sleep` before the `ENTER`.
- Adding `webDriver.wait` before the `ENTER`.
- Retrieving the active element using `webDriver.switchTo().activeElement()` and then performing my `ENTER` action. Note that using this same method, I am able to perform a `click` on the element, rather than an `ENTER`.
- Tried different ways to send the keys (using an `Actions` object, sending keys straight to the element).

Note that:

- Link is selected when the `wait` (before sending my `ENTER`) occurs.
- Replacing my `ENTER` with another `TAB` focuses the correct element.
- After every `sendKeys` call, I have the web driver wait for any ajax calls and such things. So that isn't the problem.

Any and all help/tips is appreciated. Thanks!
P.S: Needless to say I have gone through every other SO posts on this.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but are you trying to visit the link (you should "click" the link instead) or you really to send an enter key on that element? Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Really trying to send an enter key on the element. I want to test that the application supports keyboard navigation properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Chrome from version 40.X to version 43.0.2357.65-1.

Bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

What about below way

```
    Actions a=new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.name("yourlocator"))).build().perform();

    Keyboard h=((HasInputDevices)driver).getKeyboard();
    h.pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
    h.releaseKey(Keys.ENTER);
```

Thank You,
Murali

Please provide comment if it fine or not. If it is wrong please explain to improve my self.

Comment: Murali, thanks for your answer. This solution works fine if i'm in an input field. However, it still does not work when the element that I have selected is an anchor tag (link).